# Laravel Zizaco\Entrust::routeNeedsRole, how to add an exception to the route pattern?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

As title says, can I add an exception to the route pattern so admin/user/login will not get filtered?

```
Entrust::routeNeedsRole( 'admin*', array('admin'), Redirect::to('admin/user/login') );
```

EDIT:
I found a [post](http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?pid=19380#p19380) that shows we can use regex, but somehow it didn't work when I tried:

> ```
> Route::filter('pattern: ^(?!login|logout|foo|bar)(.*)$', array('name' => 'auth', function() {}));
> ```
>
> The Str::is() method which handles the pattern.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. But let me ask a question, if you're protecting the whole admin area, wouldn't an auth filter make more sense? In my opinion Entrust makes sense if you want to protect different areas of your logged in area (e.g. `admin/posts/*`)

Comment: I added some info on my question about using regex. As your question, that code comes when I installed https://github.com/andrewelkins/Laravel-4-Bootstrap-Starter-Site, I think using Entrust makes sense here as anyone who wants to access admin should have 'admin' role. Originally the code redirect to user/login (so it has no problem), but I want to separate admin and frontend login as well, so I need it to redirect to admin/user/login.